# Image is not showing at all

Tags: html, image, css, bootstrap-4

Img tag is not working for some reason.Can anyone suggest me anything?I'm using bootstrap

```
 <div id="header" class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <h1>Responsive Web design</h1>
                    <p> Hello</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Buy Mow</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btm-success">View Details</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <img src=img/a.jpg"  alt="1"> 
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you're missing the opening `"` should be `img src="img/a.jpg"`. If that doesn't work, look in your browser console for errors.

Comment: Check your `src` attribute, should be `src="img/a.jpg"`

Comment: after using  src="img/a.jpg" still does not work.

Comment: If it's not the syntax, it must be the filepath. You will get an error in your dev tools console if the browser is trying to fetch an image that it can't find on the server with the filepath you've specified in the `src` attribute.

Comment: Use Chrome debugger (F12) and go to the Network tab to see your image failing to load. You can then see if the path to the image matches to what you have on disk.

Comment: but I think I'm using right file path.It's under my img folder thats why I'm using img/a.jpg.

Comment: @NavidAnjum you can verify that (and be sure) through the Network tab in your dev tool (F12), as CodeLikeBeaker has suggested. You should also be able to find it through the Source tab.

Comment: yes ! It's saying fails to load the resource.Now, what can I do?

Comment: Correct the file path, to be safe, use an absolute filepath (full filepath; e.g: `domainname.com/img/a.jb`) rather than a relative filepath (shorthand; e.g: `/img/a.jb`)

Comment: img src="E:\xampp\htdocs\html5\bootstrap\img/a.jpg"  I've used this but still not showing.Its says not allowed to load.May be I need some permission?

Comment: Check the trailing slashes, the directions should be uniform. Also, consider taking a few minutes checking out some introductory guides to developing locally, with software like Xampp, to make sure you know how to properly reference resources, like images and other files, with the right filepaths - and how these will, or might, change when pushing to production.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone .It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure is syntax ok?

```
 <img src=img/a.jpg"  alt="1">
```

Where is the `"` after src?

```
<img src="img/a.jpg"  alt="1">
```

Comment: there is also missing div closing tag. be sure about that. also be sure about there is an image in "img/a.jpg"

Comment: Okay, lets try this; delete "img/a.jpg" and paste http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/48220dc9-e4a6-4adc-aa8c-91fc3c4b2a23/3935242a-fc53-4c14-975e-fefdfcf3bfa8_560_420.jpg. then tell is it working or not?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to close your quotation marks

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    <img src="img/a.jpg"  alt="1"> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code with this:

```
 <div id="header" class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <h1>Responsive Web design</h1>
                    <p> Hello</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Buy Mow</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btm-success">View Details</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <img src="img/a.jpg"  alt="1"> 
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This does not explain what the issue is. Simply copying and pasting a solution doesn't tell what the problem is.